# python fabric how to input \ into code branch

Tags: python, shell, fabric

i want to use fabric control my remote host

i want to fabric input shell command line to Code branch

example：

the shell code:

```
root@debian:~# cd /root
```

the fabric:

```
con.run('cd /root')
```

i want input shell code like this :

```
root@debian:~# cd \
root@debian:~# /root
```

how can i write my fabric code

i have a shell command with a long parameter， so  i need to code branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension.

```
lists = [['a','b'],['c','d','e']]
print([j for i in lists for j in i])
```

*or using itertools*

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists)))
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```